# cookies php: Cannot use isset()

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

Hi I'm trying to make a cookie that will remeber a login but it says: `Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)`. Can some one please help me?

The code that doesn't work is:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user']['id'] && !empty(isset($_COOKIE['user']['id']))){
  ...
}
```

i edited the code to: if (isset ($_logincookie['cookie_user'] && !empty($_logincookie['cookie_user']))){

but still the same problem

Comment: your `isset` has no closing `)` (parenthesis).  you probably have a typo counting on the closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the brackets. Also.. there is no need for `isset` and `empty` to be used on the same variable. `empty` verifies also if the variable is set:

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['user']['id'])){
    // do something
}
```